# How to make dropdown menu on focus

Tags: html, jquery, wordpress

I try do accessibility menu. I use jquery .focus, but there is no reaction. No classes are added.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $('.menu-item-has-children a').focus( function () {
            $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').addClass('focused');
        }).blur(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').removeClass('focused');
        });
        $('.sub-menu a').focus( function () {
            $(this).parents('.sub-menu').addClass('focused');
        }).blur(function(){
            $(this).parents('.sub-menu').removeClass('focused');
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Classes which I using are correct. There are no bugs in the console

Comment: why you need to use focus ?
May be you can use hover.
focus mostly work with input type element.

Comment: I need to access the dropdown menu from the keyboard with the tab key

Comment: I have past code below tab key also working for me.

Comment: so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Hi Check this working fine for me may be you have any other issue.

```js
    (function($) {
        $('.menu-item-has-children a').focus( function () {
            $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').addClass('focused');
        }).blur(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.sub-menu').removeClass('focused');
        });
        $('.sub-menu a').focus( function () {
            $(this).parents('.sub-menu').addClass('focused');
        }).blur(function(){
            $(this).parents('.sub-menu').removeClass('focused');
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
.sub-menu{
  opacity:0;
}
.sub-menu.focused{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <ul>
    <li class="menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <div class="sub-menu">
        sub menu working
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```